# Error in PowerShell while using arrays

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-hello

**While I am trying to assign a value to the specific index of an array it is showing the Errors.**
`PS /home/mifi> $names = @()`

`PS /home/mifi> $names[1]="abc"`

`Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At line:1 char:1
+ $names[1]="abc"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], IndexOutOfRangeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

`pwsh -v`
`PowerShell v6.0.2`

`

Comment: Show `$names.Length`.

Comment: Please show enough code to re-create.

Comment: Do you try the same with clean session? Show `$names.GetType().FullName`. Also, please, edit tags to match content of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you have to *initialize* the array first. If you know the size of the array you can do it like this:

```
$arraySize = 10
$names= 1..$arraySize | foreach { $null }
```

Consider using a **hashtable**:

```
$names = @{}
$names[1] = "abc"
```

Comment: Your `$names` will not be array, when `$arraySize` is 1. Also with `$arraySize` equals to 0 it will create array with 2 elements.

Comment: @PetSerAl Good point, Keshav should keep that in mind. Depending on his requirements a hashtable would be preferable.

Comment: @Martin Brandl, It is still showing the error by using your above code and plus I have mentioned the version of the Powershell.

Comment: @MartinBrandl actually I was using () instead of  { } curly braises as it was mention in the older book to use ( ).

Comment: We need to see your code but using @() will give you an array whereas @{} creates a hashtable. That are two different things